# How to call codeigniter function through javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

This is  not working in my codeigniter function i have the id and cannot get that id.Please help me. this is my view and i am trying to send my id through the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeajaxcall(id) {
        //alert(id);
        var r = confirm("Do you want to Delete");
        if (r == true) {
            window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_d/login/admin_link_delete_user?id='.id);?>";
        } else {
            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
            alert(x);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: use ajax for call controller function...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this line:

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_d/login/admin_link_delete_user?id='.id);?>";
```

To:

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_d/login/admin_link_delete_user');?>?id="+id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('controller_d/login/admin_link_delete_user/'.id);?>";
```

assuming that in your controller you have this method

```
function admin_link_delete_user($id){
     echo $id;// u'll get the id which you are passing through javascript    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeajaxcall(id)
{
      //alert(id);
      var r=confirm("Do you want to Delete");
      if (r==true)
      {
           $.post("<?php echo site_url('controller_d/login/admin_link_delete_user/');?>", {id:id},
           function(data) {
                alert(data+"a");
           }, 'json');
      }
      else
      {
           x="You pressed Cancel!";
           alert(x);
      }

}
</script>
```

in controller

```
function admin_link_delete_user(){
   echo $this->input->post('id');
   //perform your code
}
```